# Windows Workflow 4 within Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, windows, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I was wondering if there are any good tutorials or videos for beginners on Windows workflow 4 and how you can you a use a workflow within an asp.net page?

I want to create a basic example page that will ask the user a question and based on their answer (using a workflow decision tree) the relevant next question will be displayed.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do such example, but the approach is slightly different.

Create a workflow service with multiple receive response activities. All receive activities are related to context correlation.
Use a question data base and get current question forn database and render it.

Start button on Asp.net page  start workflow service.

Workflow Service waits for input on each receive activity and use input through submit button.

Workflow activity put next question for current user in db.